# How to separate scatterplot by different colors by group in pairs.panels() in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to draw pair plot using `pairs.panels()` in R. And separate scatterplot by different group with different colors so that it looks like the following:

[image]

Here is my initial attempt:

```
n = 1000
kindness <- rnorm(n)
beauty <- rnorm(n)
score <- kindness + beauty
c50 <- quantile(score, .50)
marriage <- ifelse(score>=c50, 1, 0)

df <- data.frame(marriage, beauty, kindness)
pairs.panels(df, digit = 3)
```

But this generates the following:

[image]

Anyone to help with this issue of separating scatter plot color within `pairs.panels()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the background colour of the dots via the "bg" option if you first change the dot 'shape' (the pch; e.g. see https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/pch-in-r-best-tips/):

```
library(psych)
n = 1000
kindness <- rnorm(n)
beauty <- rnorm(n)
score <- kindness + beauty
c50 <- quantile(score, .50)
marriage <- ifelse(score>=c50, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(marriage, beauty, kindness)

pairs.panels(df, digits = 3, pch = 21,
             bg=c("red","purple")[factor(df$marriage)])
```

[image: example_1.png]

Or you can use a colour palette like viridis or RColorBrewer, e.g.

```
pairs.panels(df, digits = 3, pch = 21,
             bg=viridis::viridis(2)[factor(df$marriage)])
```

[image: example_2.png]